# Get data from vuex without binding

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a form where I can edit the headline. If I click the reset button, the value should reset. However, since my headline comes from vuex, the initTitle  will also be affected.

```js
data() {
  return this.$store.getters[this.view];
},
initTitle() {
  return this.data.name;
},
title: {
  get() {
    return this.data.name;
  },
  set(title) {
    const target = this.view;
    this.$store.commit('update', { prop: 'name', value: title, target, id });
  }
}
```

How can I destroy the binding at the initTitel?

I have tried

```js
Object.freeze(this.data.name);
Object.assign({}, this.data.name);

//inside methods
methods: {
  initTitle() {
    return this.title;
  },
```

This screenshot shows that both get updated, if I edit the inputfield

[image]

**I found a solution for my problem**

Inside my template I removed the two-way binding **v-model** and replaced it with **:value**

```js
<input type="text" :name="'title'" :value="title" class="textfield --headline" ref="newHeadline">
```

so my vuex doesn't get any updates.

If I click the save button I take the value from my ref and comit it to my store

```js
const title = this.$refs.newHeadline.value;
this.$store.commit('update', { prop: 'name', value: title, id, target });
```

If I click the reset button I can replace the headline with the value from the store.

Comment: could you show the data object, the vuex store and the template?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim updated my question

Comment: i could not figure out the structure of your code

Comment: I don't fully understand your issue, but maybe  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data.name));`

Comment: @SølveTornøe Thank you for your reply, but that doesn't worked. I updated my answer with a solution maybe that clarifies what I wanted to achieve. But my problem was to get a value from vuex and make just a copy of the value with no bindings to vuex.